# Definition of (&&) using Lambda Expressions

Tags: haskell, lambda

I was given the following questions:

1.

```
True && True = True  
_ && _ = False
```

I wrote this as a conditional expression:

```
(&&) a b = if a then  
if b then True else False 
else False
```

2.

```
True && b = b  
False && _ = False
```

I wrote this as a conditional expression:

```
(&&) a b = if a then b else False
```

I am trying to write these two definitions given for (&&) in lambda expression, but I not exactly sure where to start or how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "lambda expression"?

Comment: We were given this as an example: add x y = x + y and it is add = \x -> (\y -> x + y) as a lambda expression

Answer (score 2):

I won't just straight up write the answer because this seems like an assignment / homework of some sort. So I'll just explain a bit how lambdas work.

Let's take a basic lambda and break it down:
`\a b -> a`

To the left side of the arrow (in this case a b) we have the arguments. These are what is passed to the lambda.

On the right side of the arrow we have the output (in this case a). So what this lambda does is takes two values and gives you the first one.

The output could be any expression for example if we restrict a and b to be numbers then we could have `myLambda = \a b -> a + b` so `myLambda 1 2` would output 3.

So to convert your definitions into lambdas just take your `if then else` statements and have those as the expression after the arrow in the lambda.

You could also use the pattern matching used in the initial definitions you gave and convert that to a lambda with a `case of` statement. This takes a value between the `case` and `of` and then you provide various expressions to be outputted depending on what the value was e.g.

```
case a of
    True -> something1
    False -> something2
```

So to put that in a lambda would give you:

```
\a b -> case a of
    value1 -> something1
    value2 -> something2
```

For the sake of completeness I will mention that there is a LambdaCase language extension that allows you to simplify:

```
\a -> case a of
    value1 -> something1
    value2 -> something2
```

to

```
\case
    value1 -> something1
    value2 -> something2
```

But this is not necessary and I certainly wouldn't worry about it as a beginner.

I hope this helps, feel free to ask for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if

```
foo bar baz = quux
```

then the two definitions

```
foo = \bar baz -> quux -- OR
foo = \bar -> \baz -> quux
```

are essentially identical to the original (up to some language warts that can be worked around by giving an explicit type signature). You can choose whichever one you like better. So,

```
(&&) a b = if a then b else False
```

can also be written as:

```
(&&) = \a b -> if a then b else False
```

Can you work out how to do the other one following this same pattern?